# Sorting Generic Array Type List With For Loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, generics

I know how to sort generic array type list using build-in methods like .sort() etc. But, I want to sort the list manually using for-loop. Can anyone help me on this method? 
Here is my ListClass

```
package AlgorithmAndDataStructures;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class ListClass<T extends Comparable<T>>{
    private static final int MAX_SIZE_OF_LIST = 100;
    /**
     * This class is having definitions for:-
     * Generic List Class Variables
     * Constructor for Creating Class Objects
     * Method: Adding a Element to the End of List
     * Method: Adding a Element at anywhere/ particular place
     * Method: Checking List is full or not.
     * Method: Checking List is Empty or Not.
     * Method: Displaying All Elements of List
     * Method: Making New Space for new element addition.
     * Method: Sorting a List
     * 
     */

    // Declaring Array and Variables
    private T[] listArray;
    private int totalElements;

    // Constructor For ListClass
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ListClass(int listSize) { // entered by the user on runtime
        totalElements = 0;
        listArray = (T[]) new Object[listSize];
    }

    // Method For Adding an Element
    public boolean addElement(T newElement)
    {
        boolean isElementAdded = true;
        if(!isListFull()) {
            listArray[totalElements] = newElement;
            totalElements++;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry, the list is full so, new element can not be added.");
            isElementAdded = false;
        return isElementAdded;
    }

    // length = totalElements
    // Method for Adding/Inserting Element in any Particular Place
    public boolean addSpecific(int newLocation, T newElement) {
        boolean elementAdded = true;
        if (!isListFull() && (newLocation >= 1) && (newLocation <= totalElements +1) )
        {
            newSpace(newLocation);
            listArray[newLocation -1] = newElement;
            totalElements++;
            }
        else {
            elementAdded = false;
        }
        return elementAdded;
    }

    // Method for Displaying The List Elements
        public void displayListElement() {
            if(isListEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, there is no element in the List!");
            }
            else 
            {
            for(int elements = 0; elements < totalElements; elements++  ) {
                System.out.println((listArray[elements]));
            }
            System.out.println("All elements has been displayed!");

            }
        }

    // Method for Checking if List is Empty or Number of elements = 0
    public boolean isListEmpty() {
        return totalElements == 0;
    }
    // Method for Checking is List is full or not. 
    public boolean isListFull() 
    {
        return totalElements == MAX_SIZE_OF_LIST;
    }

    private void newSpace( int newLocation)
    {
        // assert is a method predefined; indicator for index number
    assert (newLocation >=1) && (newLocation <= totalElements +1);
    int newIndicator = newLocation -1;
    int lastIndicator = totalElements -1;
    /**
     * For Shifting Elements to Next Indexes
     */
    for ( int sign = lastIndicator; sign >= newIndicator; sign--)
    listArray[sign +1] = listArray[sign];
    }
    // Removing / Deleting All Elements of Generic List of Type Array

    // Build in Method for sorting
    public void sort() {
        Arrays.sort(listArray, 0, totalElements);
    }

}
```

In the end of class, you can see there is a build in method to sort. It is working fine. But, I want to use for-loop. 
Here is my driver program too.

```
package AlgorithmAndDataStructures;

public class DriverListClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ListClass<Integer> listObjectInt = new ListClass<Integer>(10);
        listObjectInt.addElement(12);
        listObjectInt.addElement(17);
        listObjectInt.addElement(90);
        listObjectInt.addElement(53);
        listObjectInt.addSpecific(3, 56);
        listObjectInt.displayListElement();
        listObjectInt.sort();
        listObjectInt.displayListElement();


        // String List
        ListClass<String> listObjectStr = new ListClass<String>(4);
        listObjectStr.addElement("Suman");
        listObjectStr.addElement("Armaan");
        listObjectStr.addElement("Atif");
        listObjectStr.addElement("Tauseef");
        listObjectStr.displayListElement();
    }

}
```

**UPDATED SORT METHOD IN ListClass**

```
// Bubble Sort
    public void bubbleSort(T[] list)  {
        int n = list.length - 1;
        while (n != 0) {
        int i;
            for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (( list[i]).compareTo(list[i + 1]) > 0)  { 
                T temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[i + 1];
                list[i + 1] = temp;
                }

            }
        n= i-1;
        }
    }
```

Now, I am confused in the driver program on how to call it?

```
listObjectInt.bubbleSort(WHAT_SHOULD_BE_HERE?);
```

Looking forward to a good help! Thanks!

Comment: Any special reason for "But, I want to sort the list manually using for-loop."? Why don't you want to use built-in methods?

Comment: That is quite some contradictory requirement you have. By definition, iterating any data structure which is iterable means that when you read element n, element n - 1 is not available. How do you _even_ expect to sort in that case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: There is no special reason to do that except for my teacher requires that. He asked me to sort the list and I did it with .sort() and also with comparable class too. I have been working to make a for-loop for it but I didn't find any successful method. And now finally, after so many days of trials. I posted it on stackoverflow.

Comment: You `bubbleSort` method does not need any arguments. Just use the `listArray` field instead of `list` in the body of the method.

Answer (score 1):

There are many sorting algorithms you can use to do this (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm for a list of some of the more common ones). One of the simplest is a bubble sort which uses a `for` loop wrapped in a `while` loop.

I'll give you some pseudo-code for it - it should be relatively straightforward to convert to code.

```
while not sorted
    for each element in the list after the first one
        if the element is larger than the previous one
            swap the element with the previous one
```

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: So finally I have added a Bubble Sort Method to list class. But, confused in driver program now. I have updated the question. See the method there.

Comment: @SumanArmaan you don't need to pass the array into the `bubbleSort` method as `listArray` is a field in the `ListClass`. Just use that in the body of the method.

Comment: If I add `listObjectInt.bubbleSort();` to the driver program given above then, it is giving me an error.

Comment: @SumanArmaan You'r going to have to be more specific than that if you want help with the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think your teacher asked you to do is similar to Bubble Sort or Selection sort,and in your test ,if genericType is String ,the sort method is Incorrect.

if you  require generic sort,you can Implement Comparable.(not for-loop)

this is correct if genericType  is Interger:

```
 public void sort() {
    //Arrays.sort(listArray, 0, totalElements);
    for(int i = 0 ;i<totalElements;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<totalElements-i-1;j++){
            System.out.println(i+"+"+j);
            if((int)listArray[j]>(int)listArray[j+1]){
                T temp = (T) listArray[j];
                listArray[j] = (T) listArray[j+1];
                listArray[j + 1] = temp;    
            }   
        }
    }  
}
```

My English is very poor,I am not sure if this is what exactly you want..

Comment: I did the same before posting question here. I sorted the list using Comparable & also with ArrayList `sort()` method too for array. But he asked me to NOT use any build-in method like `sort()` or `compareTo()` And do it manually for the users. **For example:** Java has build-in methods for us to use. And so, we have to create generic class for users to use. So, build everything at your own. :/

Comment: Actually,java just give you a interface,and you can see the sort() is Incorrect sometimes. if you should build everything, what about 'String'? positive or descending,or users sort what they want sort. then you should write a interface~

Answer (score 0):

Make your type T extends Comparable and use the compareTo method of your objects

Comment: I did that. But that is also something build-in. I want for-loop manually applied. Read me comment above too.

Answer (score 0):

You CANT compare two objects without any information about them. It must implement some interface. You can create your own interface for that?